# how to display all table data to view file when click to a button in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a cart table call tbl_cart . I would like to display all the tbl_cart data to the view file (usercart.php) .Below shows the table (tbl_cart). I tried a lot ..i am new to codeigniter please help me to slove it.

id          username           useremail
....        ..........         ...........
01            abc              a@gmail.com
02            xyz              z@gmail.com

i need to display id,username,useremail values to the page usercart.php(view)

> cart.php(controller)

```
public function cartview{

   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart');

   $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();


   redirect('users/oneusercart'$resultdata)

   }
```

> usercart.php(view)

```
 <?php

   foreach($results as $result)
 {
   echo $result['username'],' ',$result['useremail'];
  }


  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function cartview{

   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart');

   $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();


   $this->load->view('usercart', $resultdata);


   }
```

[You can also read ci user guid for more details about how to load a view](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/views.html)

Answer (score 0):

why the redirect in your cart.php controller? call the view right there with

`$this->load->view('one/usercart', $resultdata);`

the results in your view you get with

```
 foreach($results as $result)
 {
   echo $result['username']; //etc,...
  }
```

read "generating Query Results" https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html and about loading views: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: resultdata

Filename: one/usercart.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lakady\application\views\one\usercart.php
Line: 7
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lakady\application\controllers\Users.php
Line: 2016
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\lakady\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: I couldn't kow your view is in the "one" subdirectory, use:  `$this->load->view('one/usercart', $resultdata);`

Comment: It error showing on your controller? If showing error on your controller for $resultdata then you can defined resultdata as array like: $resultdata = array(); $resultdata['results'] = $query->result();

Comment: defined resultdata as array  - how ??

Comment: I have mentiond $resultdata = array(); then $resultdata['results'] = $query->result(); and dont need to call $query->result_array(); and after call $resultdata please ver_dump($resultdata); and see.

Comment: sorry, I've overseen that you are using the function `$query->result_array();` to generate results. I've updated the answer concordingly...

Comment: @rowmoin -is it possible to display the details row wise ??? I have 5 results of username and i would like to view it under a heading down words

Comment: You can use table view then it can help you to show the data in row wise under a heading down.  exm:  <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>User Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
   </tr>
 <?php foreach($results as $result) {?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $result['username']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $result['useremail']; ?></td>
  </tr>
 <?php } ?>
 </table>

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do :

You do not need to redirect. You need to replace the line

> redirect('users/oneusercart', $resultdata);

with

> $this->load->view('usercart', $resultdata);

and in the view your code seems fine and it should work. Let me know if there is any issue or error.

Answer (score 0):

first step... the queries you should put in the model, no in controller. Codeigniter is a MVC framework.

With you example replace:

```
$this->load->view('$folder/$folder/...more.../file', $resultdata);
```

instead redirect

```
redirect('users/oneusercart'$resultdata)
```

"$folder/$folder/..ect/file" on the structure folder views in your codeigniter, example:

view in folder application/views/**users/oneusercart.php**

then:

```
$this->load->view('users/oneusercart', $resultdata);
```

Other example: view in application/views/**oneusercart.php**

then:

```
$this->load->view('oneusercart', $resultdata);
```

Other example: view in application/views/**users/cart/oneusercart.php**

then:

```
$this->load->view('users/cart/oneusercart', $resultdata);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Redirect](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) method redirects the url to the specified url which is another controller or router

you should be using [Views](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) to load a particular view File

*My way of doing it ..*

**My controller :**

```
public function cartview{
    $this->db->select('username')
              ->select('useremail')
              ->from('tbl_cart');
   $resultdata['results'] = $this->db->get()->result(); //result returns stdObjects
   $this->load->view('myview',$resultdata);
   }
```

**My View :**

```
 <?php

   foreach($results as $result)
 {
   echo $result->username.' \t '.$result->useremail;
  }


  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first get data from table

```
public function cartview
{ 

 $query = $this->db->query('SELECT username,useremail FROM tbl_cart');

 $resultdata['results'] = $query->result_array();
 $this->load->view('usercart', $resultdata);
}
```

and then display it on usercart view like this

```
<table>
                       <thead>
                         <tr class="bg-success">
                           <th>ID</th>
                           <th>Username</th>
                           <th>Email</th>
                         </tr>
                       </thead>
                        <?php $i=1;foreach($resultdata as 
                            $res){?>
                            <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $res->usename;?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $res->useremail;?></td>   

                  </tbody>
                  </table>
```